# Exchange 2013 - Clients can't send emails (outbound/inbound)

Tags: exchange-2013

I have a problem with the exchange server which shows the following behavior:

1. It does not send emails from outlook/mobile apps/OWA.
2. It sends mails coming from applications or from powershell both inbound/outbound. No restrictions on from/to addresses etc.
3. No trace of emails on delivery reports. It looks like they don't even exist.
4. This has started to happen after installing August's windows updates (uninstalling them did not help)
5. There is no change to receive/send connectors.

Any tips?

Comment: You've provided no information other than a vague description of the problem. We can't possibly answer this. You need to provide more details.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. Even MS specialist wasn't able to find any clue other than a guess that it was the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to call MS about this issue. After working on this for hours going through the exchange settings, time services etc. It turned out to be a corrupt database. I've created a new DB and started to move the mailboxes to the new one and everything started working fine.